# Is it safe to render URLField directly in a Django template?

Tags: django, security

I have a simple Django model that uses an URLField

```
class Place(Model):

    website = models.URLField(        
        max_length=64,
        blank=True
    )
    ...
```

The `website` field is filled by users using the application front-end. My question is: Should I sanitize this field or it can be rendered in a template directly?

```
<a href={{ website }}>The Place' website</a>
```

Could there be a security problem in doing this?

Comment: Anyway it's going to be validated when you take input with the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`URLField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1591) is just a `CharField` with [some regex validation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L44) that ensures the input resembles an URL, so your form will reject any non-URL-like strings.

Furthermore, when outputting the URL to a template, Django performs [escaping on template variables by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping):

```
By default in Django, every template automatically escapes the output of every variable tag.
```

That said, there's nothing stopping people posting valid links to malicious sites or spam sites, or adding GET parameters to the URL etc. so you still can't be sure that the site it safe.

---

As an aside, before Django 1.5, there was a `verify_exists=True/False` parameter that you could instantiate your `URLField` with which [would perform an actual web request to the URL during validation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4/django/core/validators.py#L80), to see if it existed, but [this was depreciated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#id2):

> django.db.models.fields.URLField.verify_exists will be removed. The feature was deprecated in 1.3.1 due to intractable security and performance issues and will follow a slightly accelerated deprecation timeframe.